# Magento2 Composer install is not working

Tags: magento2

**After running commend 'composer install' getting this response**

---

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  - Installing squizlabs/php_codesniffer (1.5.3)
    Downloading: Connecting...

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/zipball/396178ada8499ec492363587f037125bf7b07fcc, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit

Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+sis245-desktop+2015-10-30+2032
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/root/.composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.

Token (hidden):

------------------ Please help --------------------

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `composer install` is not working then Please try below command

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Thanks

Comment: IMHO, that is NOT the correct answer. You should do as the message says, get a token and paste it at the prompt. Your installation will proceed as normal.